# Should we explicitly write a copy constructor if the class member is a vector?

Tags: c++, stl

```
struct myType {
    vector<char*> ls;
};
```

Here `ls` is holding pointers to `char`. If a user-defined copy constructor for `myType` is not provided, will `myType`'s default copy constructor do a deep copy of `ls`?

Comment: I mean to say if vector holds any pointer to primitive or userdefined data type( pointer to class)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Here ls is holding pointer to char. If copy constructor is not provided, will default copy constructor do the deep copy?

The default copy constructor will copy all members – i.e. call their respective copy constructors.<sup>1</sup> So yes, a `std::vector` (being nothing special as far as C++ is concerned) will be duly copied.

However, the memory pointed to by the `char*` elements inside the vector will of course not, since C++ doesn’t know and doesn’t care what the pointers point to.

But the solution here isn’t to provide a custom copy constructor. It’s to use a data structure *instead of raw pointers (`char*`)* which does. And this happens to be `std::string` (or `std::vector<char>` depending on the intent).

---

<sup>1</sup> Thus creating a *transitive closure* of the copy operation – this is how deep copying is generally implemented, but of course an implementor of the copy operation can always break out of it.

Comment: "this is a good definition of “deep copy”" -- if that's a good definition of "deep copy", then what would a "shallow copy" look like? Personally I think that it's a "copy". The terms "deep copy" and "shallow copy" are meaningful if and only if one considers the elements of the `vector` as some form of indirection. If one does that, then this is a "shallow copy", but as you say `vector` doesn't care whether its elements are pointers or anything else.

Comment: @Steve In the light of the language mechanism of copy construction, the distinction IMHO only makes sense for pointer/reference assignment. But since the ctor is C++’ way of defining a copy operation, and since calling *one* ctor performs the transitive closure of this copy operation over all its members, it doesn’t make sense to call this anything but deep copying, IMHO. If you don’t provide a copy semantic inside the closure hierarchy (by using a raw pointer without associating it with a copy semantic via encapsulation), then you explicitly tell C++ to forego its copy mechanism.

Comment: Just a nit concerning the wording: the `char*` elements inside the vector very definitely are copied.  What's not copied is what they point to.  (I'm pretty sure that's what you meant.)

Comment: This is wrong to call it deep copy. Call it strictly what it is: _member copying_. Whether this is a deep or shallow copy depends highly on the structure of the data. Saying this is a deep-copy would also mean copying a pointer (not the referred object) would be a deep-copy.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: agreed, by Konrad's definition `char *a = 0; char *b = a;` is a deep copy, and it "doesn't make sense to call it anything else". In particular then it doesn't make sense to call it just "a copy", which is what the standard calls it (copy assignment in this case). So I can't accept Konrad's terminology, and I hope nobody else does either. I like "member copying" as a term -- each member is copied, and we all know what copying a pointer means. "Deep copying" involving a pointer seems to be controversial -- I think it means copying the referand, Konrad thinks it doesn't.

Comment: @Steve Let me backpedal slightly. Since `std::vector` doesn’t allow specifying a custom copy operation for its members and relies on C++’ innate mechanism (= copy construction) it makes sense for me to call this deep-copying no matter what. In fact, *every* implementation of deep copying that I know “offers” some mechanism to break out of the algorithm (akin to pointer assignment) so strictly speaking deep copying doesn’t exist *at all*. But perhaps it’s more accurate to call ctors a mechanism for implementing deep copying.

Comment: `However, your char* elements inside the vector will of course not` Yes, they will.

Comment: @Lightness I was referring to the pointees (rather than the pointers). Valid point, I’ll clarify.

Comment: A _deep copy_ means the copy is _identical_ and _distinct_. Post copy, any modifications of the source objects do not alter the copy. If a modification of the source has any affect on the copied object then a _deep copy_ has not been performed.

Answer (score 9):

> will default copy constructor do the deep copy?

Of course not. The compiler cannot know who owns the pointed-to memory.

If deep copy is required, you have to implement the copy constructor and manually copy each `char*` into new memory for the `vector` in the copied-to `object`.

If you use the `char*` as zero-terminated strings, then you should **really** use `std::string` instead. If you do, the default constructor is enough.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not.

C++ will recursively call the copy ctor of all subobjects. So it will call the copy ctor of the vector, which will in turn call the copy ctor of the  `char*` which will copy the `char*` by value. C++ will never automatically allocate memory and copy the data. It can't even possibly do that, since it does not know what the data is you are pointing at, and how much it should copy.

When you use strings, you should prefer using `std::string`, as this will do all the copying for you. If it is some binary data buffer that needs special handling, then you need to do that yourself in your copy ctor (and when you are done, think a moment about if it was really sensible to think about requiring C++ to do that for you).

When you write your own copy ctor, you always should mind the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)