# Is the nested class/struct handled the same way when passed? If a class is passed by const reference, is the nested class also handles the same way?

Tags: c++, class, struct, copy-constructor

Suppose you create a class

```
class X {
private:
    int x;
    myStruct foo; // myStruct is a struct
public:
    X(); // Constructor
    X(int, myStruct); // Parameterized Constructor
    X(const X& other); // Copy Constructor
    void example(const X& a); // Function that passes class X by const reference
    void example2(X a); // Function that passes class X by value

};
```

How is the struct data member handled when an object is passed by reference? For example, when you invoke `example(const X& a)` , is a struct copy constructor called here? How is the struct data member handled? If you invoked `example2(X a);`, is a new struct created alongside a a class?

Comment: By the way, looking at your question it seems you might be thinking that `class` and `struct` are different things. That's not the case at all, the only difference is the default access specifiers for the members.

Comment: I edited the question so that it is more clear. The other questions don't answer the crux of my question

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I made the distinctions because structs typically don't have methods. I also updated the question slightly @cigien

Comment: Ok, I've reopened. May I ask why you think that taking a reference to an object would make copies of its members?

Comment: Thank you. I don't necessarily think that. My understanding is that when an object is passed without const reference, e.g. example2(X a),  is that a new instance of type X is created, and whatever object you passed into it copied, which could be expensive. Having the parameters be const reference solves that. But if you pass an object by const ref, e.g. example(const X& a), is a copy constructor for the nested class/struct, in the example I provided, is myStruct's copy constructor called? My confusion is how is a  nested class handled when it is passed. Thank you again @cigien

Comment: The first line of the accepted answer on the [target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000636) that I used says this very clearly, "The default copy constructor will copy all members – i.e. call their respective copy constructors." What part of that is unclear exactly?

Comment: @UninterestedInNothing An object `X a;` contains a `myStruct` member `a.foo`. A reference `X &ra = a;` refers to the same object `a`, which has the same `a.foo` member embedded. There is no copy involved for `a`, so there is no copy involved for any of its members. This applies to all references, whether explicitly created as a variable, or implicitly passed to a function declared to take a reference as argument. Also, this is *un*related to the reference being `const` or not.

Comment: So in order to be more efficient, would it make more sense to provide a struct with copy constructor that has const refernce parameters?

Comment: Definitely. If a copy constructor takes an argument by copy, where would you define how this copy should happen? Defining how a *copy* happens is exactly what the copy constructor is for.